# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[15] '.AspNetCore.Correlation.OpenIdConnect cookie not found

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, okta

I'm using okta in my app so in my startup class i have this code in my ConfigureServices method to use okta

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
            {
                sharedOptions.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Account/AccessDenied");
                options.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/OktaLogin");
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            })
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                // Configuration pulled from appsettings.json by default:
                options.ClientId = Configuration["okta:ClientId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["okta:ClientSecret"];
                options.Authority = Configuration["okta:Issuer"];
                options.CallbackPath = "/authorization-code/callback";
                options.ResponseType = "code";
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.UseTokenLifetime = false;
                options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("profile");
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "email"
                };
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = ctx =>
                    {
                        ctx.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
                        ctx.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(60);
                        var userService = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserService>();
                        var userRoleService = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IUserRoleService>();
                        var rolePermissionService = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IRolePermissionService>();
                        var departmentService = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IDepartmentService>();
                        var loginSessionService = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ILoginSessionService>();
                        var claim = ctx.Principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == "preferred_username");

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(claim.Value))
                        {
                            var userInDb = userService.GetByOktaEmail(claim.Value);

                            loginSessionService.UserSessionStart(Convert.ToInt32(userInDb.Id));

                            if (userInDb != null)
                            {
                                Departments department = null;
                                if (userInDb.DepartmentId > 0)
                                {
                                    department = departmentService.Fetch(userInDb.DepartmentId);
                                }
                                var userAgent = httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];

                                //UserAgent.UserAgent ua = new UserAgent.UserAgent(userAgent);
                                var localIpAddress = GetLocalIpAddress();
                                //string browser_info = ua.Browser.Name.ToString() + ua.Browser.Version;
                                string domain = Configuration["Website:BaseUrl"];
                                List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
                                {
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, claim.Value),
                                    new Claim("UserId", Convert.ToString(userInDb.Id)),
                                    new Claim( "UserName", userInDb.FirstName),
                                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, string.Concat(userInDb.FirstName," ",userInDb.LastName) ),//userInDb.DisplayName),
                                    // new Claim("UserPosition",Convert.ToString(userPosition)),
                                    // new Claim("UserLogId", Convert.ToString(userInDb.UserLogId) ),
                                    new Claim("UserDepartment", Convert.ToString(department==null?string.Empty:department.Id.ToString())),
                                    new Claim("IPAddress", localIpAddress),
                                    //new Claim("BrowserInfo", browser_info),
                                    new Claim("Domain", domain)
                                };

                                var allUserRoleList = userRoleService.GetByUserId(userInDb.Id);
                                var allUserRole = allUserRoleList != null ? allUserRoleList.Select(m => m.Role.Name) : null;

                                if (allUserRole != null && allUserRole.Count() > 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (var userRole in allUserRole)
                                    {
                                        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role,Convert.ToString(userRole)));
                                    }
                                }

                                var permissions = userService.FetchLoggedInUserPermissions(userInDb.Id);
                                if (permissions != null && permissions.Count() > 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (var permission in permissions)
                                    {
                                        claims.Add(new Claim("Permissions", Convert.ToString(permission)));
                                    }
                                }

                                bool isAdmin = false;
                                List<int> adminRolePermissions = rolePermissionService.AdminRolePermissions();
                                if (adminRolePermissions != null && adminRolePermissions.Count() > 0)
                                {
                                    isAdmin = adminRolePermissions.All(permissions.Contains);
                                }
                                claims.Add(new Claim("IsAdmin", Convert.ToString(isAdmin)));
                                }

                                var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                                ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                            }
                        }
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },
                    OnRemoteFailure = RemoteAuthFail

                };
```

And this my configure method

```
app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseResponseCompression();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers().RequireCors("MyPolicy");
            });
```

the problem is my application is working in firefox and not working in chrome or other browser she give me this error so please someone can help me to resolved this error

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[15]   '.AspNetCore.Correlation.OpenIdConnect cookie not found.
```

Comment: Pls tell use which version of broswer and the library you use ?

Comment: @JasonPan hi my version in google chrom is 96.0.4664.110 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Does [Cagdas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59310431/what-could-cause-a-correlation-cookie-to-not-be-returned-on-specific-devices) useful to you ?

Comment: You can write your modified content as an answer, which can help more forum users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What could cause a correlation cookie to not be returned on specific devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59310431/what-could-cause-a-correlation-cookie-to-not-be-returned-on-specific-devices)